# Можно ли в название команды(или функции) поместить переменную?

Tags: python, discord

Недавно начал изучать создание ботов для discord'a на python и встретил интересный пример, который пока не понимаю, как можно реализовать:
DnD бот, который может получить команду вида `{prefix}r{d1}d{d2}`, например: `!r2d20` - 2 раза генерирует случайное число от 1 до 20.  То есть первое число (d1) отвечает за кол-во генераций, а d2 за максимальное число. Ввести можно любое число, но диапазон d1 - от 1 до 25 (при попытке ввести больше извещает о предельном числе).

Я понимаю, что можно реализовать проще (например: `!r 2 20`), но стало интересно, как именно был реализован данный пример.

Comment: Что-то я вообще не понимаю, почему второй вариант ты обработать можешь, а первый - нет.

Comment: @insolor, ты уверен, что правильно изменил заголовок?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не на 100%. Но из противопоставления вариантов `!r2d20` и `!r 2 20` я предполагаю, что затруднение именно в этом.

Comment: @insolor, он про бута говорит, я так понимаю, у бота некое подобие роутинга должно быть. Только понятия не имею, как там что устроено. Может быть дело в этом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот здесь пример просто с проверкой `message.content` как строки, без всякого роутинга: https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/#responding-to-messages Может роутинг там есть, но я глубоко не копал. Но на всякий случай откачу правку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re

command = "!r2d20"

result = re.search(r"(.)r(\d+)d(\d+)", command)
# Вкратце: точка - любой символ, \d - число, + - встречается 1 или более раз,
# скобки обозначают искомые группы символов

print(result.groups())  # ('!', '2', '20')

# Все найденные группы (соответствующие скобкам в шаблоне) распаковываем в отдельные переменные:
prefix, d1, d2 = result.groups()  

print(prefix)
print(d1)
print(d2)

# Найденные группы - это строки, поэтому для сравнения с числами их нужно преобразовывать в int
if not (1 <= int(d1) <= 25):
    print("Число не входит в диапазон")
```

С помощью модуля [parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/):

```
from parse import parse

command = "!r2d20"

result = parse("{}r{:d}d{:d}", command)
print(result)  # <Result ('!', 2, 20) {}>
prefix, d1, d2 = result

print(prefix)  # !
print(d1)  # 2
print(d2)  # 20
# Здесь d1 и d2 уже целые числа, т.к. {:d} в шаблоне поиска указывает,
# что нужно преобразовать эти части строки в числа
```